# ASP MVC - Adding columns to all tables using EF Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I need to add a set of columns to all of my database's tables (SQL Server).
I have generated my database using Code First migrations in Entity Framework 6.

Is it possible to add all these columns to all of my tables at once ? For instance, by overriding the OnModelCreating method with some specific code ?
Or do I have to add these columns to each of my Models used to update the database ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

--
Glad

Comment: Just add the columns to your models, then in the Package Manager Console run `add-migration` and then `update-database`. add- migration will create a file with commands to create your new columns, update-database will apply the changes.

Comment: If it is the same column type, then you can have a base class with the column and derive all your models from it which will obviate the need for adding this column to every class..

Comment: I think what you want is to add a column to many tables in a single go.

Comment: Yes that's it, Arijit.
But regarding to the comments, it seems it's not appropriate to do so while using Code First migrations...

Comment: Thank you Muthu, that is exactly what I wanted. It looks more clean to me to make each of my models inherit some "Base Model" containing the columns I wanted to add to all of my database's tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution, thanks to Muthu.

To automatically add those "common columns" to all my tables, I just had to create a "Base Model" containing these columns, and make all of my models inherit from it.

This avoids repeatedly adding the columns to each Model as properties, and looks cleaner I believe.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to do it like this:

1. Add these columns as properties to model classes. That's the main point of using an ORM framework such as EF.
2. Execute "Add-Migration NameForYourMigration" in Package Manager Console. This will add a new migration class to your project.
3. Execute "Update-Database" in Package Manager Console. This will update database based on instructions in migration class that you have just created.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

But I actually wanted to know if it was possible to add these columns to all of my tables at once ? instead of adding properties to each of my models.
If it's not possible, that is fine, since I only have about 10 models to update... but I was curious to know if there was a more "optimal" way of doing things.

Comment: In order to for the models to accurately represent your db tables, you _have_ to add the properties to the models, that's just how it works.

Comment: Isn't it possible to mention a new class along with the db table name and the column